# True or false: For any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A \notin \Sigma$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

My question is this. I am having a lot of trouble visualising this question so help would most certainly be welcome!

Decide whether the following statement is true or false. In each case, justify your assertion by giving a proof if the answer is true, and by a counterexample if the answer is false.

For any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A \notin \Sigma$.

Comment: What if $A$ is the empty set? Doesn't every sigma-algebra contain the empty set, by definition?

Comment: Just look at the axioms and it will be obvious. No visualisation necessary.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about the empty set!

Comment: You might want to play with the case where A is nonempty, too.

Comment: Note that $\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Reveillark. So that takes care of the case $\phi\ne A\ne \mathbb R.$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> For any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A \notin \Sigma$.

is not true since $A=\emptyset$ belongs by definition to any $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets of $\mathbb R$.

However, the modified statement

> For any nonempty set $A \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A \notin \Sigma$.

is true, since we can always choose $\Sigma=\left\{\emptyset,\mathbb R\right\}$.